# How to get a list of background processes on BlackBerry

Tags: blackberry, mobile, blackberry-jde, jde

I'm looking for something corresponding to net.rim.device.api.system.ApplicationManager.getVisibleApplications(), but including applications that might not/do not have a UI. Any ideas?

Unreasonably complicated work-around solutions welcome, I'm growing slowly more sure that there's not a simple single call to do this...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you know the application name you can detect if it is running or not by checking the size of the array containing all AppDescriptor actually running this app.

```
int codeModuleHandle = CodeModuleManager.getModuleHandle(applicationPackageName);

if (codeModuleHandle != 0) {
   ApplicationDescriptor[] apDes = CodeModuleManager.getApplicationDescriptors(codeModuleHandle);
}
```

You could imagine a code to get all installed application and then check

Comment: This works great, in combination with CodeModuleManager.getModuleHandles(), to get every module, and ApplicationManager.getProcessId(AppDescriptor) to check if they're running. Thank you!